# Flat rate shipping with max limit - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using some different flat rate shipping classes in WooCommerce. For example I'm adjusting the shipping cost with

```
1*[qty]
2*[qty]
```

I need to add a roof price. If for example a customer buys 10 of one product I want the shipping cost to be for example 5 euro.

I think it would be good enough to use a global max-shipping cost.

I'm sure I have seen it somewhere but I cannot find it now.